# How to write a VBA macro using the web page's source code

Tags: excel, vba

I want to write a macro for excel that will display the source code from the web page in a worksheet. Maybe i'm not using the correct search terms, but all i'm finding are examples of how to write a macro that will return a web page's source code once you provide the URL. I have the URL and the code, but i'm not sure how to imput it into excel using VBA. If anyone could link me to a proper example of how to do this or show me how it's done, I would be greatly appeaciative.

The website is a printer device status page, here is the source code I would need excel to display:

```
 <p id="SupplyPLR0" class="data percentage">50%*</p>
 <p id="SupplyPLR1" class="data percentage">60%*</p>
 <span id="MachineStatus" class="machine-status">Ready</span>
 <strong id="BlackCartridge1-EstimatedPagesRemaining">11400</strong>
```

The site itself is an HP device status webpage for a printer.

Any and all help is welcome!

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to display the HTML on your spreadsheet, you can try something like the following.

```
Dim IE As Object
Dim Doc As Object

Sub DisplayMyInfo()
    InitializeIE ("http://www.ILoveMyPrinter.com")
    ActiveWorksheet.Range("A1") = ReturnOuterHTML("SupplyPLR0")
    ActiveWorksheet.Range("A2") = ReturnOuterHTML("SupplyPLR1")
    ActiveWorksheet.Range("A3") = ReturnOuterHTML("MachineStatus")
    ActiveWorksheet.Range("A4") = ReturnOuterHTML("BlackCartridge1-EstimatedPagesRemaining")

    Set Doc = Nothing
    Set IE = Nothing

End Sub

Sub InitializeIE(URL As String)
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.navigate URL
    Do While IE.readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Loop
    Set Doc = IE.document
End Sub

Function ReturnOuterHTML(NodeID As String)
    Dim strHTML As String
    strHTML = Doc.getElementById(NodeID).outerHTML
    ReturnOuterHTML = strHTML
End Function
```

I haven't gotten the chance to test it out.  Let me know if you have any issues.

Cheers, LC

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! When I try to run this after plugging in the correct URL though, it tells me that the object variable or with block variable is not set. Do you know how I would fix this?

Comment: Unfortunately i'm still getting the same error, still trying to figure out what's causing it.

Comment: It's not indicating which line returns the error unfortunately, still trying to figure that out.

Comment: There is no such thing as ActiveWorksheet. I think this was probably a mind-fart and they meant ActiveSheet.